# Using numpy from a local directory

Tags: python, numpy, condor

Is there a way to use numpy from a local directory without adding the directory to the path for python? I am asking because I am running jobs on condor on machines that do not have numpy installed. I have no way of directly adding numpy to these machines, and I do not believe I can change the path on these machines. I have looked at [How to tell Condor to dispatch jobs only to machines on the cluster, that have "numpy" installed on them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864766/how-to-tell-condor-to-dispatch-jobs-only-to-machines-on-the-cluster-that-have) regarding determining if a machine has numpy, and I would prefer to run on all machines if possible, and I'm not sure I can alter the machine's classId anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always be able to use

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/local/numpy")
```